# What is the optimal way to load form data into a string and then to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this the optimal way to load form data into a string and then to `localStorage` ?

I came up with this on my own, and I am not good in programming. It works, for what I need, but I am not sure if it's a bulletproof code?

```
<script>
    var sg = document.getElementById("selectedGateway");
    var sd = document.getElementById("selectedDestination");
    var dm = document.getElementById("departureMonth");
    var dd = document.getElementById("departureDay");
    var dy = document.getElementById("departureYear");
    var rm = document.getElementById("returnMonth");
    var rd = document.getElementById("returnDay");
    var ry = document.getElementById("returnYear");
    var ad = document.getElementById("adults");
    var ch = document.getElementById("option2");

    $("#searchRequestForm").submit(function() {
        var string = 'From: ' + sg.value + ' \nTo: ' + sd.value + ' \nDeparture: ' + dm.value + '/' + dd.value + '/' + dy.value + ' \nReturn: ' + rm.value + '/' + rd.value + '/' + ry.value + ' \nNumber of adults: ' + ad.value + ' \nNumber of children: ' + ch.value;
        localStorage.setItem("string", string);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This question would be better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I am still learning stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer a table driven approach so there is no repeated code ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself)):

```
var ids = [
    "selectedGateway", "From: ", 
    "selectedDestination", "\nTo :",
    "departureMonth", "\nDeparture: ", 
    "departureDay", "/",
    "departureYear", "/",
    "returnMonth", " \nReturn: ",
    "returnDay", "/",
    "returnYear",  "/",
    "adults", " \nNumber of adults: ",
    "option2", " \nNumber of children: "];

var submitStr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i+=2) {
    submitStr += ids[i+1] + document.getElementById(ids[i]).value;
}
localStorage.setItem("string", submitStr);
```

Comment: I like this approach, it keeps the string intact.

Comment: I can confirm this works, but for some reason a part of my othe JavaScript code stopped working. `<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#searchRequestForm").submit(function() {
      return popitup('{site_url}site/submit_search_by_email'),
      document.getElementById('page-loader').style.display='block';
    });
</script>`

Comment: @user1736969 - If you still need help, I would suggest you post a different question and include whether your browser reports any script errors in the error console and include the `popitup()` code.  FYI, you can't really put multiline code in comments and have it be readable.  Multiline code has to go into questions or answers.

Answer (score 6):

I would use something like the following so that I could deal with an object and its properties rather than a big string. Note that other than the jQuery selectors, this is pure JavaScript.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/grTWc/1/

```
var data = {
    sg: $("#selectedGateway").val(),
    sd: $("#selectedDestination").val()

    // items here
};

localStorage.setItem("mykey", JSON.stringify(data));
```

To retrieve the data:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage["mykey"]);
alert(data.sg);
```

See Also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: If `JSON.stringify` exists, why wouldn't `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @MattBall - I got into the habit of using `$.parseJSON()` for IE7 support, but that's pointless if I'm assuming support for `JSON.stringify()`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely try this as well. looks simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function such as the one below to directly get the values by id so then it would be simpler when you build your string.

```
function form(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```